# Access is denied when creating a file in a directory

Tags: java, file, inputstream, fileinputstream, cifs

I've a strange problem  with creation of a file in the remote shared network folder.

**Use case:**

1. My development environment is located in some local VM.
2. Application calculates some data. Creates and saves a xml file under specific path. (example: C:/ProgramData/MyApp/exp/heregoestofile.txt).
3. You can specify the file location. So it could be a local folder within the VM, or remote shared network folder.

**Problem:**
When I run the application on my local machine, everything is working fine if i specify the file location within the local VM and xml file is created without any problem. However my issue is that, in my application I have an option to specify where the file should be created. So, for my use case, file has to be created in some shared remote network directory. When I try to create the file, I get the following exception:

```
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|directory is created: \\Win-ris3devae1\hfshare\ERS01[2021-02-08 10-42-35-000]
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|some directory is about to be created: \\Win-ris3devae1\hfshare\ERS01[2021-02-08 10-42-35-000]
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|[org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session-/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:49945] ERROR com.ricoh.sdced.ers.xmlparser.XMLParser - An exception occured in writeXMLDocumentToFile method: 
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|directory is created: \\Win-ris3devae1\hfshare\ERS01[2021-02-08 10-42-35-000]
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|java.io.IOException: Access is denied
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|till here it comes without any problem
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|creating a new file with path: \\Win-ris3devae1\hfshare\ERS01[2021-02-08 10-42-35-000]\index.xml
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1014)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at com.ricoh.sdced.ers.xmlparser.XMLParser.writeXMLDocumentToFile(XMLParser.java:90)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at com.ricoh.sdced.ers.server.MailHandler.saveMetadataToFolder(MailHandler.java:58)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at com.ricoh.sdced.ers.server.MailHandler.saveMailToFolder(MailHandler.java:47)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at com.ricoh.sdced.ers.server.MailHandlerFactory$Handler.data(MailHandlerFactory.java:65)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.command.DataCommand.execute(DataCommand.java:58)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.server.RequireTLSCommandWrapper.execute(RequireTLSCommandWrapper.java:32)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.server.RequireAuthCommandWrapper.execute(RequireAuthCommandWrapper.java:35)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.server.CommandHandler.handleCommand(CommandHandler.java:86)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.runCommandLoop(Session.java:233)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.run(Session.java:147)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
INFO|4288/0|Service Ricoh ERS|21-02-08 10:42:36|    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The code I use to create the file is this:

```
public void writeXMLDocumentToFile(String folderPath) {
        try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(folderPath + XML_FILE_NAME)) {
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, YES);
            transformer.setOutputProperty(XSLT_INDENT_AMOUNT_STRING, INDENTATION_AMOUNT);
            Source s = new DOMSource(this.document);
            Result res = new StreamResult(stream);
            transformer.transform(s, res);
        } catch (TransformerException | IOException e) {
            logger.error(EXCEPTION_IN_WRITEXMLDOCUMENTTOFILE_METHOD, e);
        }
    }
```

Note: You can say that I might not have the permission for writing & reading to this remote shared folder. I already gave it and its not the case unfortunately.I did the following test:

1. My development environment is in a VM.
2. I open the command line in my development VM and do something like echo hello >> \someaddress\myapplication\hello.txt  and its created all fine. That means remote folder is opened for write read access within my vm.

So this means i dont have any network permission issue, as I can already create a file in remote shared network folder, inside this VM using a command line.

Comment: Which user is the JVM running as?

Comment: admin user is running it

Comment: Exactly which "admin user"?  Were you logged in as that exact same user when you did your `echo hello >> ...` test?

Comment: Are you executing the file using `sudo`?

Comment: It seems that my application which is running as a windows service is not running as a admin account so it doesnt have permission to write a file. How could I change this in tomcat?

Comment: Starting Tomcat itself as admin will result in running all sub-routines as administrator.